# Yii2: use fxp assets plugin or asset-packagist?

Tags: linux, windows, composer-php, bower, yii2-advanced-app

Seems like yii2 has some unresolved conflict between
using the asset-packagist.org method, or the older
fxp assets plugin.
I am now working with a project, intended to use the
asset-packagist. All settings appear OK, but Yii2 seems to ignore
it all and insist on using a bower directory that does not exist.
Using the asset-packagist method, this directory is called bower-asset.

The settings: To make this work, we use (in common/config/base.php):

```
'aliases' => [
'@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
'@npm' => '@vendor/npm-asset',
 ],
```

...and in composer.json we set:

```
 "repositories": [
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
}
],
```

That does not help, however, still getting the error:

```
 The file or directory to be published does not exist: 
 C:\....common\config/../../vendor/bower/semantic/dist
```

Also tried to switch fxp off with (in composer.json):

```
 "config": {
"fxp-asset": {
        "enabled": false
    }
  },
```

Also tried command:

```
 composer global remove fxp/composer-asset-plugin  --no-plugins
```

Same thing.

Note: The project was developed in Linux, I am now trying open it in Windows 10 and XAMPP on localhost. Feel free to tell me if Windows-related.

Comment: Double check your configuration - if Yii is trying to access `vendor/bower/semantic/dist`, then your `'@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset'` seems to be ignored. Or you have hardcoded `vendor/bower` path somewhere.

Comment: Hi
Thanks. Nothing is hard-coded. But I found out: if I rename the directory to "bower", it now says:
"The file or directory to be published does not exist: C:\....common\config/../../vendor/bower-asset/jquery/dist" !
Notice, now it is jquery, not semantic (and the directory exists!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work, I had to choose the fxp-plugin, and to let go of the asset-packagist way (it simply does not work, given the knowledge I have at this point), like this:

- Removed the reference to `asset-packagist.org` from repositories section in composer.json (in my case I removed the whole repositories section.:

> ```
>    "repositories": [
>     {
>     "type": "composer",
>     "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
>     }
>     ],
> ```

- Install the latest composer fxp-plugin, currently 1.4.6:

> composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4.6"

- Removed the @bower -> bower-asset (and those for npm) aliases in common/config/base.php.
- Then, now it finds the correct path if you rename the bower-asset folder in vendor to "bower". But you should never change anything in the vendor folder, instead, add this `fxp-asset` section to "config" in composer.json:

> ```
>  "config": {
>             "process-timeout": 1800,
>             "fxp-asset":{
>                 "installer-paths": {
>                     "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
>                     "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

- Then remove the vendor folder, remove the Composer.lock file and run `composer install` .

Comment: Did you tried remove `vendor` directory and run `composer install` *before* switching to fxp-plugin?

Comment: No. I ran the fxp plugin install before composer install.

Comment: You should try it - it looks like the whole problem was because part of your dependencies has been installed when `fxp-plugin` was present (and `vendor/bower` was configured path) and part of them have been installed when `asset-packagist` was used (and `vendor/bower-asset` was configured path). Reinstalling the whole `vendor` should fix these problems, so you can use asset-packagist.org.

Comment: Now I did the whole thing anew, on an Ubuntu VM from scratch, this time being completely sure no fxp-plugin is present, but same thing happens.